# Scalaz ValidationNel is not working

Tags: scala, scalaz

I tried to use Scalaz(7.2.18) to validate data. I tried following code:

```
    def hasDob: ValidationNel[AdtError, String] =
      enc.dob.map(_.success).getOrElse(MissingAdmitDate(enc).failureNel)

    def hasAdmitDt: ValidationNel[AdtError, Timestamp] =
      enc.admitDT.map(_.success).getOrElse( MissingAdmitDate(enc).failureNel )

    def hasTimezone: Validation[AdtError, DateTimeZone] =
      fac.timezone.map(_.success).getOrElse( UndefinedTimezone(fac).failureNel )

    (hasDob |@| hasAdmitDt |@| hasTimezone) { (dob, admitTime, facilityTz) => ... }

    case class MissingDateOfBirth(enc: EncAdt)
      extends AdtError { def logString = s"Txn ID: ${enc.transactionID}  Missing DOB: ${enc.accountNumber}" }

    case class MissingAdmitDate(enc: EncAdt)
      extends AdtError { def logString = s"Txn ID: ${enc.transactionID}  Missing Admit Date: ${enc.accountNumber}" }
```

**UPDATE START**

```
//enc
case class EncAdt(transactionID: Long,
     dob: Option[String],
     admitDT: Option[Timestamp],
     ...
)

//fac
case class Hl7Facility(
  timezone: Option[DateTimeZone],
     ...
)
```

**UPDATE END**

But above code is throwing compile-time error:

```
Type mismatch: Validation[Nothing, String], actual: scalaz.ValidationNel[MissingDateOfBirth, Nothing]
Type mismatch: Validation[Nothing, String], actual: scalaz.ValidationNel[MissingAdmitDate, Nothing]
Type mismatch: Validation[Nothing, String], actual: scalaz.ValidationNel[UndefinedTimezone, Nothing]
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Any solution for above issue is highly appreciable.

Comment: Could you also show signature of your `enc`? For example what type hsa `admitDT` and which `success` is called in the `map` and which `getOrElse` is called later?

Comment: I've updated the question with `enc` and `fac` signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `NonEmptyList[A]` is invariant so you can't upcast `NonEmptyList[MissingAdmitDate]` to `NonEmptyList[AdtError]`. So the code that compiles directly should probably look like this:

```
def hasAdmitDt: ValidationNel[AdtError, Timestamp] = {
  enc.admitDT.map(_.successNel[AdtError])
    .getOrElse(MissingAdmitDate(enc).asInstanceOf[AdtError].failureNel)
}
```

This doesn't look nice but I don't see a way to make Scala compiler infer generics the way you need it in this form. However you can create your own custom methods instead of `successNel` and `failureNel`.

I mean something like this:

```
object AdtValidation {

  type AdtValidation[A] = ValidationNel[AdtError, A]

  implicit class AdtValidationSuccess[A](val value: A) extends AnyVal {
    def successAdt: AdtValidation[A] = Validation.success[NonEmptyList[AdtError], A](value)
  }

  implicit class AdtValidationFailure(val value: AdtError) extends AnyVal {
    def failureAdt[A]: AdtValidation[A] = Validation.failureNel[AdtError, A](value)
  }
}
```

and then you can do something like this:

```
import AdtValidation._
def hasAdmitDt: AdtValidation[Timestamp] = {
  enc.admitDT.map(_.successAdt).getOrElse(MissingAdmitDate(enc).failureAdt)
}
```

But then, if you go this way anyway, you may also add something like this

```
object AdtValidation {

  type AdtValidation[A] = ValidationNel[AdtError, A]

  implicit class AdtValidationOptionOps[A](val value: Option[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def validateNonEmpty(emptyError: => AdtError): AdtValidation[A] = value.map(_.success[NonEmptyList[AdtError]]).getOrElse(Validation.failureNel[AdtError, A](emptyError))
  }  
}
```

so that you can do

```
def hasAdmitDt: AdtValidation[Timestamp] = {
  enc.admitDT.validateNonEmpty(MissingAdmitDate(enc))
}
```

P.S. it looks suspicious that in your code sample inside `hasDob` you fail with `MissingAdmitDate` rather than something like `MissingDob`

Comment: Great! Above worked perfectly for the case I'd mentioned. I've other issues while I tried to implement fold. If you could help me out on those issues as well.
`enc.admitDT.fold[ValidationNel[AdtError, String \/ Int]](
              MissingAdmitDate(enc).failureNel
            )`

Here the issue is: fold doesn't take type parameter

Comment: @Sujit, sorry but I don't understand your question. `admitDT` is `Option[Timestamp]` and there is no `fold` with one parameter on `Option` not to mention other inconsistencies in your example. The closest guess I have is that you actually need something like this `enc.admitDT.fold[AdtValidation[String \/ Int]](MissingAdmitDate(enc).failureAdt)((t: Timestamp) => -\/(t.toString).successAdt)`. If this is not what you really want, you probably should create another question where you can put your real example and its description in words.

Comment: I've added another question for some clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088505/validationnel-error-after-upgrading-scalaz-to-7-2